# How can Activation function do its task?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, sigmoid

I have a simple question. I know that the main purpose of activation function is to convert an input signal of a node to an output signal. And that output signal is gonna used as an input in the next layer. But I dont have any idea about the way that activation function such as sigmoid do this in classification problem.
All I know is about converting. 
Could any one pleas clarify this to me?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question at all, can you clarify?

Comment: Sure. I want to know that how do activation functions do their tasks. How can their define the output of a neuron given an input or set of input.  Or simply explain that what is the role of activatom function. Thanks

Comment: I think you have a confusion, because activations don't do tasks, they are just functions (like max(0, x)) used to introduce non-linear behavior in the network. How the output is defined is just the mathematical expression of the activation function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my quesion with a picture of an slide in Andrew Ng machine learning class. As you see there are 3 layers input hidden and output. As you see in the hidden layer we have activation of each unit. I want to know tabout the definition of it and discover why he wrote activation into each neuron

Comment: Sorry but that is not really on-topic here, its not a programming question. Your question belongs to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms the function gets inputs and assigns some **weights** to the inputs.
Then the activation function calculates the value (eg :- Sigmoid).
Then it compares the value with the threshold value assigned . If its more than the threshold value then it backtracks (back propagation Algorithm). and adjusts the **weights**. You can find more details at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation